# Thrift HttpServer in Java

Tags: java, http, thrift

It is very strange but I could not find any example of a Thrift Http Server in java. C++ & Python have a THttpServer implementation. Java has a TServlet, but no actual transport provided. Is there a way to create a Thrift Http Server in Java, without using a Servlet container or any other extra Http library?

Comment: Yes, this https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/java .

Comment: @KostasC The mentioned link is a TCP server.

Comment: What would be the benefit of having a bespoke (and probably inferior) implementation of a HTTP Server?

Comment: Just scanned the Java lib and indeed there seems to be none. Very likely that nobody needed it until now because there are other (better) solutions - like servlets. However, if you plan to implement one on your own, I'd suggest to discuss that on the mailing lists before.

Comment: I am also looking for a simple thrift http server. The closest I found is line's armeria: http://line.github.io/armeria/